# How can you remove the list html from GWcode categories add-on?

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories

I'm using GWCode Categories add-on (http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) to output a custom field from a category.

However, i cannot see anyway to get it not to output the list html i.e

- custom field content

- i just want it to output the custom field content and nothing else.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, i had a spelling error in there, the answer is:

```
style="linear"
```

Sorry!